# Best way to write thousands of strokes in WPF canvas

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, canvas

I have to implement writing by touch on Wacom tablet ( like on paper) and I need to render **up to 200 strokes per second** in WPF Canvas. The problem is that after about 20s of constant writing it gets a bit laggs and the laggs grows. I store all strokes in **HashSet**. I thought about taking screen shoot when HashSet contains over 600 elements and set it as a background image and clear the HashSet, but after ~30 screen shoots it gets a bit blurred. Do you have any idea how to make it better?

Comment: You could use WriteableBitmap

Comment: Will try. Thanks for response

Comment: Canvas or InkCanvas?

Comment: Canvas. It must be canvas because inkCanvas doesnt handle mouse events as we wish

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `WriteableBitmap`. This is very fast, but it works by writing individual bytes to bitmap, so if you need to apply effects to the drawing, then you have to write them yourself. This is an example of how you can use `WriteableBitmap`. It takes ~100 ms in debug mode to draw 1000 lines (each made out of 1600 points) on 1600 x 1200 px image on my computer, but I'm sure this can be optimized.

I'm just randomly drawing lines, but you can get events from `Canvas` and capture positions of stylus and pass them after each stroke.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private WriteableBitmap _bitmap;
    private readonly Random _random = new Random();
    private readonly Stopwatch _stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
    private const int White = 0x00000000;
    private const int Red = 0x00FF0000;

    private int _width;
    private int _height;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        CanvasImage.Loaded += OnLoaded;
    }

    private async void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        _width = (int)DrawableCanvas.ActualWidth;
        _height = (int)DrawableCanvas.ActualHeight;
        _bitmap = new WriteableBitmap(_width, _height, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Bgr32, null);
        CanvasImage.Source = _bitmap;

        while (true)
        {
            unsafe
            {
                for (var index = 0; index < _width * _height; index++)
                    *((int*)_bitmap.BackBuffer + index) = White;
            }

            _stopwatch.Start();

            for (var index = 0; index < 1000; index++)
            {
                var start = _random.Next(0, _width);
                var points = Enumerable.Range(0, _width).Select(x => new Point((x + start) % _width, x % _height));
                UpdateImage(points);
            }

            Debug.WriteLine($"Last 1000 draws took: {_stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds} ms");
            _stopwatch.Reset();

            await Task.Delay(300);
        }
    }

    private void UpdateImage(IEnumerable<Point> points)
    {
        _bitmap.Lock();

        foreach (var point in points)
        {
            var x = (int)point.X;
            var y = (int)point.Y;
            var offset = _width * y + x;
            unsafe
            {
                *((int*)_bitmap.BackBuffer + offset) = Red;
            }
        }

        _bitmap.AddDirtyRect(new Int32Rect(0, 0, _width, _height));
        _bitmap.Unlock();
    }
}
```

And view:

```
<Grid>
    <Border Width="1604" Height="1204" BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="Blue">
        <Canvas x:Name="DrawableCanvas">
            <Image x:Name="CanvasImage"></Image>
        </Canvas>
    </Border>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Thanks for this solution, unfotunately unsafe code (                    *((int*)_bitmap.BackBuffer + offset) = Red;
) throws System.AccessViolationException: 'Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.' when I'm writing using pen which is giving me 200 point per second. Have you any solution for this  ?

Comment: @Hawex You have something wrong in your pointer calculations. You have to double check how you modify offset. If you have a problem with calculating this, it would be best to create a separate question for it on this site.

Comment: Are you sure, that it's problem with pointer? Some points are added to bitmap, exception is thrown randomly when writing.

Comment: @Hawex I'm pretty sure, based on you wrote. You are probably either incrementing or decrementing offset too much and it overflows outside your bitmap's `BackBuffer`. There are other reasons why it might not work though. Without seeing code I am unable to tell you 100% what the reason is. Please create a separate question for this.

Comment: You are right. I'm tried to write on pixels out of bitmap. Now everything seems to be ok.